# Dynamic div width after drop using jquery ui

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I need to create a workflow builder. I use jquery ui for drag'n'drop. 
I drag elements onto the div with the canvas id. Here is its css

```
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
```

The problem is that if the chart is large, then we need to add a scroll. When I drag an element, a scroll appears. When dropped, the element remains in the correct position, even if this position is larger than the width of the canvas itself (for example, `canvas.width() == 800px, droppedElement.x == 2000px`). But if I start dragging this element again, it will immediately move to the edge of canvas (i.e. `draggedElement.x == 800px`). 
I tried increasing the width of the canvas (based on dropped element coordinates), but that only added horizontal scrolling to the page. Then for the parent of the canvas (col-lg-8) I added `overflow: hidden`, but that didn't help at all, the container was just clipped. 
I have no more ideas on how to fix this. Hope for your hints

Draggable

```
  $('.create-flowy').draggable({
    containment: '#canvas',
    appendTo: '#canvas',
    helper: function(event, ui) {
      return $(this).clone();
    }
  });
```

Drop

```
$('#canvas').droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.helper.attr('class').includes('flowchart-operator')) return

    const relativeLeftPos = ui.helper.position().left + document.getElementById('canvas').scrollLeft;
    const relativeTopPos = ui.helper.position().top;
    const blockTitle = ui.helper.find('p')[0].textContent;
    
    // if (relativeLeftPos > $(this).width() ) {
    //   $(this).width(relativeLeftPos + 100);
    // }
    createAndAppendNewBlock(relativeLeftPos, relativeTopPos, blockTitle); //jquery.flowchart, it's not important
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in jquery.flowchart, look at `.draggable ({drag:` into library source code. Hope it helped someone